# Get next value for each of values from next table CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have the following table: 
dbo.split

```
Name  Time   
Alex  120
John  80 
John  300 
Mary  500
Bob   900
```

And then another table dbo.travel

```
Name Time
Alex  150
Alex  160 
Alex  170
John  90
John  100
John  310  
Mary  550
Mary  600 
Mary  499 
Bob   800
Bob   700
```

For each value in table split I need to find the next value in table travel. I tried to do it with CTE a with ROW_NUMBER() to get next by group, but there's no way I can group by correct value, since dbo.split can containt multiple values for the same name.

I'm looking for the following output:

```
Name  Time TravelTime 
Alex  120  150
John  80   90
John  300  310
Mary  500  550
Bob   900  NULL
```

Here's what I have so far but it fails because split table can have multiple records per person:

```
;with result as (
 select t.*, 
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition BY t.Name order by t.Time) as rn 
 from travel t join split s 
 on t.Name = s.Name and t.TIME>s.Time
 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `apply`:

```
select s.*, t.time
from split s outer apply
     (select top (1) t.*
      from travel t
      where t.name = s.name and t.time > s.time
      order by t.time asc
     ) t;
```

In this case, `apply` is doing essentially the same thing as a correlated subquery, so you could phrase it that way as well.

Comment: That's genius. Thanks so much, always forget about outer apply and think in "loop" mode :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try as below

```
   Select * from(Select 
        Name,t.time,t1.time, 
       Row_number() over (partition by
        Name,t.time order by t1.time) rn
        from split t
       Join travel t1 on t.time <t1.time and 
          t.name =t1.name) 
          where 
           rn=1;
```